# How to print out a specific tokenized entity

Tags: python, nltk

I'm having a problem with my code. I have .txt file named test.txt which contains sentences and I have a dataframe which contains all tokenized words on those sentences. My problem is that I want to specifically find and print out the specific token and keeping their position number. I tried some if statements() but it seems it's overwriting the counting of index of each word.

```
def output ():
        currCount = 0
            for words in read():
                add = len(words)
                word_new = [' '.join(df.loc[t].values.tolist()) if t 
                in df.index is not None else t for t in word_tokenize(words)]
                tag = ' '.join(word for word in word_new);
                print('First:' + str(currCount) + '\n' + 'Last:' + str(currCount + add)
                + '\n' + 'Tag: ' + tag + '\n' + 'word: '+words + '\n')
                currCount += add + 1
                if words is ".":
                    currCount = 0

#Sample output                                       #Output that i want
#First:0                                             #Assume that i only want 
#Last:1                                              #PERSON tags
#Tag: PERSON                                         
#word: I                                             #First:0 
                                                     #Last:1
#First:2                                             #Tag: PERSON
#Last:6                                              #word: I
#Tag: NOTHING
#word: like                                          #First: 0  
                                                     #Last: 3
#First:7                                             #Tag: Bob
#Last:12                                             #word: PERSON
#Tag: FOOD
#word: pizza

#First:13
#Last:14
#Tag: NOTHING
#word: .

#First:0
#Last:3
#Tag: Bob
#word: PERSON

#First:4
#Last:9
#Tag: NOTHING
#word: likes

#First:10
#Last:15
#Tag: FOOD
#word: pizza

#First:16
#Last:17
#Tag: NOTHING
#word: .
```

A sample sentence inside of my test.txt file is

```
   I like pizza .
   Bob likes pizza .
```

and a sample of the tag that i made

```
  I      PERSON 
  Like   NOTHING
  Pizza  FOOD
  .      NOTHING
  Bob    PERSON
  likes  NOTHING
  pizza  FOOD
  .      NOTHING
```

```
The output that i want: 
Assume that i only want PERSON tags.

First:0 
Last:1
Tag: PERSON
word: I

First: 0  
Last: 3
Tag: Bob
word: PERSON
```

Comment: How are you making this dataframe? Won't it be easier if, along with the tags you add the start and end indices for each word in the dataframe itself and then only filter out `PERSON` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a cleaner and easier way to do it:

```
words = []
for line in data:
    start = 0
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(line):
        word_tag = {}
        word_tag['First'] = start
        end = start + len(word)
        word_tag['Last'] = end
        word_tag['Word'] = word
        # word_tag['Tag'] = <your statement for tagging>
        words.append(word_tag)
        start = end + 1

df = pd.DataFrame(words)
```

This is how your dataframe will look like:

```
First   Last    Word    Tag
0       1       I       PERSON
2       6       like    NOTHING
7       12      pizza   FOOD
13      14      .       NOTHING
0       3       Bob     PERSON
4       9       likes   NOTHING
10      15      pizza   FOOD
16      17      .       NOTHING
```

You can then filter out rows using:

```
df[df['Tag'] == 'PERSON']
```

Output:

```
First   Last    Word    Tag
0       1       I       PERSON
0       3       Bob     PERSON
```